# List all nodes related to a term which is related to another one

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, panels

I searched many times how to list all nodes related to a term which is related to another one, but without success...

Can you help me ?

Actually I want to do something like this:

My page (where a term is defined) <- A term linked to the previous defined one <- The nodes related to this term.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Don't have time for full answer, so just a hint (feel free to earn rep making an answer from it ;) ): Use Views module, define relationship from node to term1 and from term1 to term2. Filter on term2.

Comment: Hmmm... Does not work :-(
Strange!

Comment: That should work fine with views. Can you specify, how is your term related to another term?

Comment: <My Node> related to <Term> related to <General Term>

 - They are related by a custom field

Comment: Ok I found the problem... Actually no, I didn't find it but I re-create some panels / views from scratch, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have [Views](https://drupal.org/project/VIews) installed, install the Views module.

1. Create a taxonomy view
2. Add filter to filter your taxonomy.
3. Add a relationship to other taxonomy you want.
4. Add the relationship to nodes.

Comment: Creating a taxonomy view won't help as he needs node lists. Node lists being the output; here a node views needed to be created with a relationship to taxonomy 1 and 2 (term 2 can be supplied from CONTEXTUAL FILTERS)

Comment: @heshanlk, when I create a taxonomy view, I can't add nodes in the relationships... Strange...

Comment: @Jeet You can output referenced node list from a taxonomy view too, that make lot easier to add relationships between taxonomies.

Comment: I'm sure it's possible... Maybe with Panels ?

Comment: No, when you are adding a Relationship you should be able to find "Relate each Content with a TAXONOMY NAME" field?. Add it in to your views.

Comment: Yes, but not with the right taxonomy name... I don't really understand :-s

Comment: That's strange. How do you have your content fields set up?. Do you have a taxonomy reference field in your content type?

Comment: Yes... Maybe I found my problem...

I have about 7 node types in 7 different vocabularies (with 7 different custom reference fields, I think that's the problem) with many terms, each of these terms are related to 1 other vocabulary's term...

Comment: Rhhh... That was not the problem!